# Using a custom Angular filter as a cellFilter for ui-grid columnDefs defined in an Angular constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In my Angular app (`myApp`) I have a custom filter (`myFilter`) and I am using UI Grid with multiple grids (`myGrid1`, `myGrid2`, etc.) to display my data in various view of my app. Since many of the columns are used on more than one grid, I have placed their column definitions within an Angular constant for use throughout my app.

I am not having any luck using `myFilter` as a cellFilter for a subset of the column definitions in the constant. You can't inject a filter into a constant and injecting the constant into a config() also does not work (unknown provider error).

Here's a glimpse at what my code looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['MyFilter'])
  .constant('MyColumns', {
    firstName: {
      cellClass: 'myCellClass',
      name: 'firstName'
    },
    lastName: {
      cellClass: 'myCellClass',
      // cellFiler: 'myFilter', // DOES NOT WORK
      name: 'lastName'
    }
    // etc.
  })
  .filter('myFilter',
    function() {
      // leaving out what filter does for brevity
      return;
    }
  )
  .controller('MyController',
    function (MyColumns) {
      var myData; // leaving out data for brevity

      var myGrid1 = {
        columnDefs: [
          MyColumns.lastName,
          MyColumns.firstName
          // etc.
        ],
        data: myData
        // etc.
      };
    }
  )
  /*
  .config(function (MyColumns) {
    MyColumns.lastName.cellFilter = 'myFilter'; // DOES NOT WORK
  })*/
;
```

Is there a way I can use `myFilter` on the column definitions in the constant? Thanks for your help!

versions: Angular 1.5.8, UI Grid 3.2.6

Answer (score 0):

I think you just simply has wrong DI name, based on doc when you register a filter `filterName` you should inject dependency name `<filterName>Filter`

So, if your register `.filter('myFilter',...` you should inject `['myFilterFilter']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of cleaning up and fixing the code in my question, I got a working solution. See below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'MyFilter'])
  .constant('MyColumns', {
    firstName: {
      cellClass: 'myCellClass',
      cellFilter: 'myFilter',
      name: 'firstName'
    },
    lastName: {
      cellClass: 'myCellClass',
      name: 'lastName'
    }
    // etc.
  })
  .controller('MyController',
    function(MyColumns) {
      var vm = this;

      var myData = [{
        firstName: 'Hillary',
        lastName: 'Clinton'
      }, {
        firstName: 'Donald',
        lastName: 'Trump'
      }, {
        firstName: 'Gary',
        lastName: 'Johnson'
      }];

      var myGrid1 = {
        columnDefs: [
          MyColumns.lastName,
          MyColumns.firstName
          // etc.
        ],
        data: myData
          // etc.
      };

      angular.extend(vm, {
        myGrid1: myGrid1,
        myData: myData
      });
    }
  )
  .config(function(MyColumns) {
    MyColumns.lastName.cellFilter = 'myFilter';
  });

angular.module('MyFilter', [])
  .filter('myFilter',
    function() {
      return function(input) {
        return '▢ ' + input;
      };
    }
  );
```

```html
<link href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as MyCtl">
  <div ui-grid="MyCtl.myGrid1"></div>
</div>
```

(I also upgraded from UI Grid 3.2.6 to 3.2.9, not sure if that had an impact)